# 3 columns with images - bottom aligned on desktop but not on resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive, image-resizing

I am working on a 3 column layout where there are 3 images in the first and third column and 2 bigger ones in the middle column.

It basically looks like this:

[image: column example]

I have cut the images as they are on design and managed to make this work and be aligned well on desktop but as soon as the screen goes narrower the middle column becomes shorter than the other two. Maybe I have to create images in a different ratio than on design, I don't know but maybe there is a way to deal with this using CSS or jQuery.

```css
.col-set {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1220px;
}

.col-set .col-4 {
  float: left;
  width: 30.5%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-set .col-4.middle-cat {
  width: 39%;
}

.col-set .col-4 a {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #d80281;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.col-set .col-4 a:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.col-set a img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.col-set a strong {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #655c62;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: ease all 500ms;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-set">
  <div class="col-4 left-cat">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/704x624/a0a922/000000&text=+" alt=""><strong>Product Category</strong></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/704x624/a0a922/000000&text=+" alt=""><strong>Product Category</strong></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/704x624/a0a922/000000&text=+" alt=""><strong>Product Category</strong></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 middle-cat">
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/912x996/a30101/000000&text=+" alt=""><strong>Product Category</strong> </a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/912x996/a30101/000000&text=+" alt=""> <strong>Product Category</strong> </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 right-cat">
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/704x624/a0a922/000000&text=+" alt=""> <strong>Product Category</strong> </a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/704x624/a0a922/000000&text=+" alt=""> <strong>Product Category</strong> </a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/704x624/a0a922/000000&text=+" alt=""> <strong>Product Category</strong> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is jsfiddle too](https://jsfiddle.net/ovdafztp/)

Comment: You'll need to provide the CSS that you currently have for these items so we can theorize on what the issue might be and what the solution should be.

Comment: Have you considered using Flexbox and/or CSS Grid? I feel like much of this can be simplified that way.

Comment: @CodeSpent yes I tried that too, but unless I missed something it didn't help much. I can have the columns have equal heights, but images just don't follow

Answer (score 0):

Your example images are 624 and 996 px high. 624x3 is a different value to 996x2. It'd be easier to have the images add up to the same height rather than try and move them around using CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point there, but I have just tried to make the 2 middle column images have the same height in total as those 3 in the first or last column but nothing's changed :( 
Now I have 3 small images that are 704x624 and the 2 big ones are 857x936.

Comment: I played with your fiddle and expected that adding padding, of the 120 pixel difference, to the first middle product item would sort it but found that 
    <div style="padding-bottom: 36px;">
around it seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Hi Jason, sorry but around which element exactly did you add that div? Feel free to update the fiddle if you like, thanks

Comment: It'd be tidier doing it through CSS but here's the interim workaround:    <div class="col-4 middle-cat">
<div style="padding-bottom: 36px;">
<a href="#"> <img src="http://oi67.tinypic.com/whktpt.jpg" alt=""><strong>Product Category</strong></a>
</div>